# Jetpack Compose: expand image with restricted height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a list of elements in which each one is an expanded image on top and a title on the bottom.

The image must expand all of its available width but it must have a fixed height.

If the image is big enough I can do it, but if the image has a portrait aspect ratio it doesn't expand as I would like.

This is what I have right now:

[image]

The first image has a portrait aspect ratio, I would like it to expand to the available width but maintaining a fixed height.

This is the code for the list and each element:

```
@Composable
private fun List(memes: List<Meme>) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(memes) { index, meme ->
            ListElement(meme, isFirst = index == 0, isLast = index == memes.size - 1)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ListElement(meme: Meme, isFirst: Boolean, isLast: Boolean) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(
                start = marginLat,
                top = if (isFirst) 8.dp else 0.dp,
                end = marginLat,
                bottom = if (isLast) 8.dp else 0.dp
            ),
        elevation = 4.dp
    ) {
        Column {
            Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(meme.url),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp)
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            )

            Text(meme.name, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add a sample image with which it doesn't work? works fine with a plain portrait image to me

Answer (score 0):

use ContentScale.FillWidth

```
Image(
       painter = rememberImagePainter(meme.url),
       contentDescription = null,
       contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
       modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxWidth()
               .height(100.dp)
               .padding(8.dp)
               .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
      )
```